# Why my Email server Mark as Spam?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

Hi I have installed emails sserver and I was configuration with SPF, DKIM not relay. but still mark as spam when sent into another mailserver.

here my header when sent into gmail.

```
Delivered-To: test@email.ac.id
Received: by 10.67.5.134 with SMTP id cm6csp1162899pad;
        Mon, 12 Jan 2015 14:59:06 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.66.249.226 with SMTP id yx2mr47651949pac.112.1421103545987;
        Mon, 12 Jan 2015 14:59:05 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <developer@siteA.id>
Received: from serverB.id (serverB.id. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id sk3si24842126pab.208.2015.01.12.14.59.05
        for <test@email.ac.id>;
        Mon, 12 Jan 2015 14:59:05 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of developer@siteA.id does not designate xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of developer@siteA.id does not designate xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=developer@siteA.id;
       dkim=pass header.i=@siteA.id
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by serverB.id (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6ECDE18222D
    for <test@email.ac.id>; Mon, 12 Jan 2015 17:59:03 -0500 (EST)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at serverB.id
Received: from serverB.id ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (serverB.id [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id XndeuiUPTr3z for <test@email.ac.id>;
    Mon, 12 Jan 2015 17:58:58 -0500 (EST)
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (unknown [36.72.188.178])
    by serverB.id (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 55CD6181BF3
    for <test@email.ac.id>; Mon, 12 Jan 2015 17:58:58 -0500 (EST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=siteA.id; s=mail;
    t=1421103538; bh=eoiZDmxu8BwVN9n+nMx/jqQf4L+771kN8+jJD3SIF0Q=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:From;
    b=VLR6ZOWGuZHhE3+DVbXBZAwu5xGhyBipe/ciwF+rlyKzmC8D0ikd2hOlynW8ob5Q5
     h7/6fiNpBxHAma/g9aGCMeVfJGX2jdxazfLiVcfY+MnrrzjoOhE4Iy5NdWBEOww5vj
     xmSsHgOoSAoZQ1WNe6P3TWzDpfDOKaH9qj+VTcG8=
Message-ID: <54B451B1.7030708@siteA.id>
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 05:58:57 +0700
From: info <developer@siteA.id>
Organization: eneloop
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/31.3.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: test@email.ac.id
Subject: attaaat
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Antivirus: avast! (VPS 150112-1, 01/13/2015), Outbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean

tatas

---
This email has been checked for viruses by Avast antivirus software.
http://www.avast.com
```

someone can tell me what is wrong in here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current SPF is this:

```
eneloop.id.             1799    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx:smtp.microad.co.id -all"
```

This says "MX servers for the domain smtp.microad.co.id can send email for this domain, and nothing else".

However, smtp.microad.co.id is a server, not a domain, so has no MX servers.  Effectively you are saying that no servers can legitimately send email for this domain.

You probably want this:

```
eneloop.id.             1799    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

Which means the MX server for eneloop.id can send email for eneloop.id - and `smtp.microad.co.id` is listed as an MX server for it.

Or you want:

```
eneloop.id.             1799    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a:smtp.microad.co.id -all"
```

This says that the IP address that `smtp.microad.co.id` resolves to can send emails for eneloop.id

Both these options achieve the same thing - the former means that if you choose to use a different email server to send emails in the future, your SPF will still be valid.

Comment: hi I have change like your suggesting , but still sent to spam folder ?

Comment: Can you post the new headers since the SPF change?  Note that it can take 30 minutes for Google to refresh its copy of your SPF record.

Comment: Wow after waiting some hour ago and try again that is work , now email sent not mark as spam thanks you.

Comment: hi paul after some try my email go to spam again. can we discuss this in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20206/mail-marsk-as-spam ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) to the list of permitted senders - there is probably a tool on the account page of your domain registrar.

Said record should look something like this:

```
TXT    siteA.id    “v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ~all”
```